# Mat declaration: declaration dimensions and size() are differents

Tags: c++, opencv

I declare a Mat as

```
Mat mu = Mat::ones(2000, 256, CV_64F);
```

and when I do

```
cout << size(mu);
```

the output is `"[256, 2000]"`. This only happens in some parts of the code and I can understand that.
­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

There is a method `static cv::Mat::MatExpr ones (int rows, int cols, int type)`, that construct `cv::Mat` objects.

But method `Size` return the number of rows and the number of columns in the [reverse order](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html).

It looks correctly and no any issues here.
Give more information, what's wrong here for you?